# Error in event handler for downloads.onChanged: TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to chrome extensions and I'm currently developing a simple extension that opens the folder of the last downloaded file. If the file was deleted, it opens the downloads folder.
Whenever I run my code this error logs in to my console.
Any help on how to improve my code is appreciated.

manifest.json

```js
{
 "name" : "Last Download",
 "version" : "1.0",
 "manifest_version" : 2,
 "description" : "Opens the last downloaded file",
 "background" : {
  "scripts" : ["background.js"]
 },
 "icons" : {
  "64" : "icon.png"
 },
 "browser_action" : {
  "default_icon" : "icon.png",
  "default_title" : "Last Download"
 },
 "permissions" : [
  "background",
  "downloads",
  "downloads.shelf",
  "storage"
 ]
}
```

background.js

```js
var State=false;
chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(delta) {
 chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(false);
 if (delta.state.current == 'in_progress'){
  State=true;
 }
 else if (delta.state.current == 'complete'){
  State=false;
  chrome.storage.local.clear;
  chrome.storage.local.set({'lastDownloaded' : delta});
  chrome.downloads.show(delta.id);
 }
 chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(true);
});
function click(){
 if (State==false){
 chrome.storage.local.get('lastDownloaded' , function(result){
  chrome.downloads.search({id : result.lastDownloaded.id}, function(file){
   if (file[0].exists == false) {
    chrome.storage.local.clear;
    chrome.downloads.showDefaultFolder();
   }
   else if (file[0].exists == true){
    chrome.downloads.show(result.lastDownloaded.id);
   }
  });
  
 });
 }
 if (State==true){
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://downloads/"});
 }
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(click);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`state`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#property-downloadDelta-state) is an optional property to the [`downloadDelta`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#property-onChanged-downloadDelta) Object. When you get the error, that property does not exist. It is undefined. Thus, when you try to use `delta.state.current` you are attempting to get the `current` property of an undefined property, which generates the error you are seeing.

You will need to take a look at the properties available on your `delta` Object to see what property, other than the lack of a `state` property, gives you the information you need to perform whatever operation you are desiring to do when you are in that situation wrt. downloads/user interaction. You can do this through the normal debugging methods of either using a debugger, or using `console.log(delta)` to give you that information. You then correlate the properties that exist and their values to the states that you want to handle, and test for the properties being those values.

If you just want to avoid the error, you should be checking for the existence of the `state` property. If you want, you can just test that `delta.state` evaluates to true. However, given that you are getting a property of it, it is best to check that it is an Object and not `null`:

```js
if(typeof delta.state === 'object' && delta.state !== null) {
    if (delta.state.current == 'in_progress'){
        State=true;
    } else if (delta.state.current == 'complete'){
        State=false;
        chrome.storage.local.clear;
        chrome.storage.local.set({'lastDownloaded' : delta});
        chrome.downloads.show(delta.id);
    }
} else {
    //This is the condition under which you are getting your error. you need to determine
    //  what you want to do here, if anything.
    console.log('downloads.onChanged: In a state not specifically handled. delta=',delta);
}
```